# looking for an expression meaning "depending on you"

Tags: phrase-request

> After working as a patent agent for more than four years, I aspire to
>   become a patent attorney. Without an educational background in law, I
>   am not qualified to take the bar exam in China. My family and I have
>   soberly weighed the sacrifices that would be required if I studied in
>   the United States. I am willing to do whatever it takes to pursue your
>   JD program; my dream of a better career ___.

I am looking for an expression meaning "depending on you" to fill in the blank.

It is a bit tricky because it is a law school admission essay. I don’t want to sound too emotional like I am begging for your admission. On the other hand, I don’t want to sound too cool-headed. Indeed my dream depends on you.  Your program is the only way to realize my dream. Your program means a lot to me.  I want to strike a balance.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I'm not sure that you are writing this correctly.  You want them to offer you a place on the course. You need to tell them why it would be good for them to do this.  "Because I really really want it" is no reason for them to offer you a place. You should consider whether you want this this in at all.

Comment: So why aren't you studying law in China? I think you need a transition to explain why it's better for you to study law in the US (and then I assume practice in the US).

Comment: Points well taken.  :)  Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am willing to do whatever it takes to pursue your JD program; your program is **the key to unlock my dream** of a better career.

Not all keys are made of metal; as Wordnik says:

> **key** (noun) a determining factor in accomplishing or achieving something.

Moreover, many English speakers use the verb *unlock* when they use the word *key* in this metaphorical sense. For example, you can find books and blog posts with titles like:

- [7 Keys to Unlock Your Passion and Become Successful](https://havingtime.com/7-keys-to-unlock-your-passion-and-become-successful/)
- [7 Keys to Unlock Your Potential, Achieve Your Dreams](https://www.earlytorise.com/lessons-from-tom-bilyeu/)
- [4 Keys to College Admissions Success](https://books.google.com/books?id=F3kRBAAAQBAJ): *Unlocking the Gate to the Right College for Your Teen*
- [The biggest key to unlocking success as a leader](https://boeason.com/biggest-key-unlocking-success-leader-youre-not-will-fail/)

Answer (score 1):

"My dream of a better future depends on you" is correct and idiomatic English. "... is dependent on..." is also possible, and you can slightly de-personalise (and so make more formal) by saying "...on your decision."

However, I would cut it completely.  You should be focussed on telling them why they really want to have a student like you, instead of telling them why really want to study with them.